# wordpress travel photohgraphy theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking for a theme in wordpress for develop a website of travel photography. I checked hundreds of themes and I the one I would like is no longer available. Someone knows something similar? I would like to have a map in the main page with the links in all the places I've visited. Thank you so much.

http://themes.purethemes.net/?theme=wptraveller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is better theme As it is multipurpose http://themeforest.net/item/avada-responsive-multipurpose-theme/2833226

Comment: So with that one is possible to get what I want? I don't mind if I have to change code but I would like to make it simple. Thanks for answer!

Comment: Yes you can use that theme for your travel site too.Please accept my answer if you find it useful. :)